# Why is an error popping out when i am trying to use priority_queue with parameters as pointer to a structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

## Priority Queue throws an error with pointers. When I try to use structure pointers as parameter for priority queue and use comparator function the code gives an error , but priority seems to work fine with objects. ##

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 struct data
 {
    int cost;
    int node;
    int k;
    data(int a,int b,int c):cost(a),node(b),k(c){};
 };

 struct cmp
 {
    bool operate(data *p1,data *p2)
    {
    return p1->cost<p2->cost;
    }
 };

 int main ()
 {

    priority_queue<data*,vector<data*>,cmp> pq; 
    pq.push(new data(0,2,3)); //This line throws an error stating (   required from here) and there is nothing written before required.

 }
```

Comment: `bool operate(data *p1,data *p2)` -- See anything wrong here?  What is "operate" supposed to do?  Is this how you overload the function call operator?  Second, include the proper headers, not that `bits..` stuff.  Third, naming your structs and variables with terms that could clash (like `data`) is another issue.

Comment: You need to use `bool operator()(data *p1,data *p2)` instead

Comment: There is already a `std::data` that exists in C++, and it more than likely name clashes with your `struct data`.  Your code shows all of the reasons why that `bits..` header and `using namespace std;` is nothing but trouble.

Comment: @RemyLebeau still not working sir.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sir i have tried changing everything and nothing works.

Comment: @BadalJoshi [works fine for me](https://ideone.com/1iTlfU)

Comment: [No errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/263d0fedc7155dbc).

Comment: @RemyLebeau -- The code messes up with C++17.  I believe it has to do with `std::data`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau When i do the way you said it says                                               Line 12: Char 5: error: 'operate' declared as function returning a function

Comment: Actually i was solving a problem in leetcode and this error wont go.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sir i have compiled the code in codeblocks as well and have done everything you have said.I have even changed the data-types. Sir I already know the language i used the terms to make the code readable and easy to interpret.

Comment: So did you take the code I posted at the link?  If you knew the language, why the mistake of using `operate`?  And what is meant by "readable and easy to interpret"?  The code has several mistakes in it that will cause it to not compile.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am really sorry sir. The code worked. in dev. Really thankful for your help. Next time I will for sure keep the things in mind.

Comment: @BadalJoshi there is no "operate" in the code I showed you. The correct name is "operator()"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes sir thanks a lot sir that clears my doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 things wrong with your code:

1) There is a [std::data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data) that exists in C++ 17, yet you have a `struct data` with the addition of `using namespace std;` before the declaration of `struct data`.  This could cause a naming clash.

2) The function call operator is `operator()`, not `operate`.

3) You're using the dreaded `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, which not only is non-standard, causes all sorts of issues pertaining to item 1) above.

Here is your code that addresses all of these issues above:

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <queue>

 struct data
 {
    int cost;
    int node;
    int k;
    data(int a,int b,int c):cost(a),node(b),k(c){};
 };

 struct cmp
 {
    bool operator()(data *p1,data *p2)
    {
        return p1->cost < p2->cost;
    }
 };

 int main ()
 {
    std::priority_queue<data*, std::vector<data*>,cmp> pq; 
    pq.push(new data(0,2,3)); 
 }
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0ceae36d10f07fe)